# What's the best way to get a bootstrap 2.0 modal to display when a page loads.

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

For example, I have a modal that must be displayed before a user can log in.

Answer (score 2):

That is the default behavior of the bootstrap modal script, e.g.:

```
show |  boolean/default: true | Shows the modal when initialized.
```

Of course, as long as you initialize the script call on window load or in the body, like so:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal({
        keyboard: false
    })
});
```

[Documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/bvY8a/1/show/) with the default behavior left untouched. And here is another [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/bvY8a/2/show/) with the `show : false` option added to the call.